# JPA - Persisting LOB properties on Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, orm

I have a field defined like this

```
private java.sql.NClob details;
```

When I try to build to create an entity manager, I get the following exception :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.sql.NClob, at table: messages, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(details)]
```

The table doesn't exist yet in the database.

What should I tell Hibernate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how I solve my problem :

```
@Column(length=100000)
private String details;
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Lob` indicates that the property should be persisted in a Blob or a Clob depending on the property type: `java.sql.Clob`, `Character[]`, `char[]` and `java.lang.String` will be persisted in a Clob. `java.sql.Blob`, `Byte[]`, `byte[]` and `Serializable` type will be persisted in a Blob.

```
@Lob
public String getFullText() {
    return fullText;
}

@Lob 
public byte[] getFullCode() {
    return fullCode;
}
```

If the property type implements `java.io.Serializable` and is not a basic type, and if the property is not annotated with `@Lob`, then the Hibernate serializable type is used.

Comment: What is "the Hibernate serializable type" ??

Comment: With this solution I get numbers in the database field.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using postgresql, maybe it's easiest to map the column as a normal clob, rather than a nclob, since postgresql doesn't have separate nvarchar etc. types.

Comment: WIth this tips, I don't get the exception anymore but the column is empty in the database and I know the column should contain data.